# How Can I Identify Cloud Computing Applications? Can I Say Like Facebook Is Cloud Application?

Tags: sharepoint, amazon-ec2, cloud

How can i identify cloud computing applications? Can i say like Facebook is cloud application ?

This is ma worst doubt.May be the stupid question i ever asked here.

As per my understanding cloud means storing data,processing data etc using the internet. Example in gmail we can access using internet where we can see
inbox,outbox etc like a standalone software. Another example SP sites where we can do so many things.

So can i say Facebook is also cloud since we can store,we can do so many things there..
Please explain.

Example for cloud sites?

Can i say all sites like this site etc are in cloud ?

Comment: have you tried searching "cloud computing" in google (and yes, it is also cloud computing site)

Comment: please explain how is this connected to java and c# and sharepoint (which is NOT cloud computing)

Comment: C# and Java developers will be aware of cloud computing i believe.

Comment: I searched in google and kerned some basic idea about cloud. What i asked here is my doubts...If you say cloud means managing things using web then all web applications will be cloud right?

Comment: 1) they will not be better aware than ruby/php/javascript/many more languages 2) tags are not meant for that purpose

Comment: SO is not the place for these type of questions (try ask.com or yahoo answers). classic "closed as too broad" case.

Comment: ok ...I guess you are working in cloud technologies If am correct and if you understand my question please answer..else please ignore this...Thanks

Comment: ok.... I guess you are able to read my comments. please follow the advice i have written.

Answer (score 1):

A cloud application (or cloud app) is an application program that functions in the cloud, with some characteristics of a pure desktop app and some characteristics of a pure Web app. A desktop app resides entirely on a single device at the user's location (it doesn't necessarily have to be a desktop computer). A Web app is stored entirely on a remote server and is delivered over the Internet through a browser interface.

Comment: The answer "A cloud application is an application that functions in the cloud" is like saying "a dog is an animal that eats dog food"